# UpdatePanel in usercontrol does not update client controls

Tags: c#, asp.net, ajax

I have been scratching my head for hours over this.  I have a user control, which has labels, textboxes, etc.  All of these are wrapped in an update panel.  I have a button in the uc, which when clicked, it changes a label.

When I put this uc in a form/page, no matter what I do, I do not see the label change. It is changed server side but not client side.  I tried updatemode always, conditional with triggers, I tried everything.  The scriptmanager is fine, if I copy the code to its own page it works just fine.  The scriptmanager is on the page, not the uc, so that is not it.

Does anyone have an example of this or anything?

aspx:

```
<%@ Page Title="" Language="C#" MasterPageFile="~/KezberProjectManager.Master" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeBehind="WebForm1.aspx.cs" Inherits="KezberProjectManager.WebForm1" %>
<%@ Register assembly="AjaxControlToolkit" namespace="AjaxControlToolkit" tagprefix="asp" %>
<%@ Register assembly="KezberProjectManager" namespace="KezberProjectManager" tagprefix="cc1" %>

<%@ Register src="ProjectView.ascx" tagname="ProjectView" tagprefix="uc1" %>

<asp:Content ID="Content1" ContentPlaceHolderID="head" runat="server">
</asp:Content>
<asp:Content ID="Content2" ContentPlaceHolderID="ContentPlaceHolder1" runat="server">
    <div>

            <uc1:ProjectView ID="ProjectView1"  runat="server" PID="76"  />

 </div>

</asp:Content>
```

uc:

```
<%@ Control Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeBehind="ProjectView.ascx.cs" Inherits="KezberProjectManager.ProjectView1" %>
<%@ Register assembly="AjaxControlToolkit" namespace="AjaxControlToolkit" tagprefix="asp" %>    
<style type="text/css">
        .style1
        {
            width: 100%;
        }
    </style>
<asp:UpdatePanel ID="UpdatePanel1" UpdateMode="Conditional" ChildrenAsTriggers="false" runat="server">
    <ContentTemplate>
        <asp:Panel ID="pnl" runat="server">
    <div id="kez_header">
        <table class="style1">
            <tr>
                <td>
                    <h4 runat="server" id="main_label">
                        Project</h4>
                </td>
                <td align="right" valign="middle">
                    <asp:Button ID="btnTasks" runat="server" CssClass="btn btn-primary"
                        Text="Tasks" Width="81px" onclick="btnTasks_Click" />

                </td>
            </tr>
        </table>
    </div>
     <div class="form-horizontal">
        <div class="control-group">
            <label class="control-label" for="<%=txtTitle.ClientID%>">
                Title</label>
            <div class="controls">
                <asp:TextBox ID="txtTitle" placeholder="Title" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="control-group">
            <label class="control-label" for="<%=txtDescription.ClientID%>">
                Description</label>
            <div class="controls">
                <asp:TextBox ID="txtDescription" placeholder="Description" runat="server" Rows="3" TextMode="MultiLine"></asp:TextBox>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="control-group">
            <label class="control-label" for="<%=lblEstimatedHours.ClientID%>">
                Estimated Hours</label>
            <div class="controls">
              <label class="checkbox label-block">
                    <div id="lblEstimatedHours" runat="server">
                        Data</div>
                </label>
            </div>
        </div>
     <div class="control-group">
            <label class="control-label" for="<%=txtColor.ClientID%>">
                Color</label>
            <div class="controls">
                <asp:TextBox ID="txtColor" runat="server" Width="80px" MaxLength="6"></asp:TextBox>
                <asp:FilteredTextBoxExtender ID="txtColor_FilteredTextBoxExtender" 
                    runat="server" TargetControlID="txtColor" ValidChars="0123456789abcdefABCDEF">
                </asp:FilteredTextBoxExtender>
                <asp:ColorPickerExtender ID="txtColor_ColorPickerExtender" runat="server" 
                    TargetControlID="txtColor" SampleControlID="btnColor" PopupButtonID="btnColor">
                </asp:ColorPickerExtender>
                <asp:Button ID="btnColor" runat="server" Text="" CssClass="btn-color" Width="25px" />
            </div>
        </div>
        <asp:Button CssClass="btn" ID="btnEdit" runat="server" Text="Save Changes" onclick="btnEdit_Click" 
          />
    </div>
    </asp:Panel>
    </ContentTemplate>
    <Triggers>
        <asp:AsyncPostBackTrigger ControlID="btnEdit" EventName="Click" />
    </Triggers>
</asp:UpdatePanel>
```

uc code:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Transactions;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.UI;
using System.Web.UI.WebControls;
using LibKezberProjectManager;
using LibKezberProjectManager.Logic;
using LibKezberProjectManager.Utility;
using LibKezberProjectManager.Web;

namespace KezberProjectManager
{
    public partial class ProjectView1 : System.Web.UI.UserControl
    {
        private int workingID = -1;
        private string pid;
        private Project workingProject = null;

        public String PID
        {
            get
            {
                return pid;
            }
            set
            {
                pid = value;
                if (!HandleRequestType())
                {
                    HandleOnClickDisabled();
                    HandleMainLabel();

                    pnl.DefaultButton = "btnEdit";

                    if (workingProject != null)
                    {
                         PopulateEditMode();
                    }
                }


            }
        }


        protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

        }

        protected void btnTasks_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
           // Response.Redirect(String.Format("Tasks.aspx?id={0}", workingProject.ProjectID));
        }



        public void HandleOnClickDisabled()
        {
            //btnEdit.Attributes.Add("onclick", "this.disabled=true;" + GetPostBackEventReference(btnEdit).ToString());
        }

        public bool HandleRequestType()
        {
            string strId = pid;
            bool invalidPage = false;

            //id is required, can be new or valid id
            if (strId == null)
            {
                invalidPage = true;
            }
            else
            {
                int.TryParse(strId, out workingID);

                workingProject = ProjectManager.GetProject(workingID);
                //must be valid project
                if (workingProject == null)
                {
                    invalidPage = true;
                }

            }

            if (invalidPage)
            {
                //Response.Redirect("Forbidden.aspx");
            }

            return invalidPage;
        }

        public void HandleMainLabel()
        {
            main_label.InnerText = workingProject.ProjectTitle;
        }

        public void PopulateEditMode()
        {
            txtTitle.Text = workingProject.ProjectTitle;
            txtDescription.Text = workingProject.ProjectDescription;
            if (workingProject.EstimatedHours != null)
                lblEstimatedHours.InnerText = workingProject.EstimatedHours.ToString();
            else
                lblEstimatedHours.InnerText = "";

            if (workingProject.Color != null)
            {
                System.Drawing.Color color = System.Drawing.Color.FromArgb((int)workingProject.Color);
                txtColor.Text = String.Format("{0:X2}{1:X2}{2:X2}", color.R, color.G, color.B);
            }

        }



        protected void btnEdit_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            KezErrorList errors = new KezErrorList();
            bool didSomething = false;
            bool changedColor = false;

            using (var scope = new TransactionScope())
            {
                try
                {
                    if (txtTitle.Text != workingProject.ProjectTitle
                        && txtTitle.Text.Length > 0)
                    {
                        didSomething = true;

                        bool success = ProjectManager.ChangeProjectTitle(
                            workingProject.ProjectID, txtTitle.Text);

                        if (!success)
                        {
                            errors.Add("There was a problem changing the title.");
                        }
                    }
                    else if (txtTitle.Text != workingProject.ProjectTitle)
                    {
                        errors.Add("A title is required.");
                    }

                    if (txtDescription.Text != workingProject.ProjectDescription)
                    {
                        didSomething = true;

                        bool success = ProjectManager.ChangeProjectDescription(
                            workingProject.ProjectID, txtDescription.Text);

                        if (!success)
                        {
                            errors.Add("There was a problem changing the description.");
                        }
                    }

                    try
                    {
                        System.Drawing.Color color =
                            ColorConversion.GetSystemDrawingColorFromHexString("#" + txtColor.Text);

                        if (workingProject.Color == null || color.ToArgb() != (int)workingProject.Color)
                        {
                            changedColor = true;
                            if (!ColorManager.ChangeProjectColor(workingProject.ProjectID, color.ToArgb()))
                            {
                                errors.Add("There was a problem changing the color.");
                            }
                        }
                    }
                    catch (Exception)
                    {
                        errors.Add("The color provided is invalid.");
                    }

                    if (errors.Count() == 0 && didSomething)
                    {
                        if (!SyncManager.Instance.UpdateProject(workingProject))
                        {
                            errors.Add("There was a problem syncing with 1 or more sources.");
                        }
                    }



                    if (errors.Count() == 0)
                    {
                        scope.Complete();
                    }
                }
                catch (Exception ex)
                {
                    errors.Add("An unknown error has occured.");
                }

            }

                if (errors.Count() > 0)
                {
                   // master.ShowErrorAlert(errors.GetErrorString());
                }
                else if (didSomething || changedColor)
                {
                    //master.ShowSuccessAlert();
                    //refresh
                    if (workingProject != null)
                    {
                        workingProject = ProjectManager.GetProject(workingProject.ProjectID);
                    }

                    HandleMainLabel();
                    PopulateEditMode();
                }

                UpdatePanel1.Update();
        }
    }
}
```

Master:

```
<%@ Master Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeBehind="KezberProjectManager.master.cs" Inherits="KezberProjectManager.KezberProjectManager" %>

<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head runat="server">
    <title></title>

    <!-- Le styles -->
    <link href="assets/css/bootstrap.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
    <link href="assets/css/bootstrap-responsive.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
    <link href="assets/css/kezblu.styles.css" rel="stylesheet"/>

    <style type="text/css">

    </style>
    <!-- Le HTML5 shim, for IE6-8 support of HTML5 elements -->
    <!--[if lt IE 9]>
      <script src="http://html5shim.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/html5.js"></script>
    <![endif]-->
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.0.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="assets/js/kezcommon.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">

        $(document).ready
    (
        function () {

            createAutoClosingAlert('.success_alert', 6000);
        }
    );

        function createAutoClosingAlert(selector, delay) {
            var alert = $(selector).alert();
            window.setTimeout(function () { $(alert).slideUp() }, delay);
        }

</script>  

    <asp:ContentPlaceHolder ID="head" runat="server">
    </asp:ContentPlaceHolder>
</head>
<body>
    <form id="form1" runat="server">

    <asp:ScriptManager ID="ScriptManager1" runat="server" EnablePartialRendering="true">
    </asp:ScriptManager>
           <div class="navbar navbar-inverse navbar-fixed-top">
      <div class="navbar-inner">
        <div class="container">
          <a class="btn btn-navbar" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".nav-collapse">
            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
          </a>
          <a class="brand" href="default.aspx">KezBlu</a>
          <div class="nav-collapse collapse">
            <ul class="nav">

<asp:Repeater runat="server" id="MenuRepeater">
  <headertemplate>

  </headertemplate>
  <itemtemplate>
     <%# Eval("Content") %>
  </itemtemplate>
  <footertemplate>

  </footertemplate>
 </asp:Repeater>

              </ul>
             <div id="auth">
                 <asp:HyperLink id="lnkSignIn" runat="server">Sign In</asp:HyperLink>
                 <br />
                 <asp:LinkButton ID="lnkSignOut" runat="server" onclick="lnkSignOut_Click">Sign Out</asp:LinkButton>

             </div>

          </div><!--/.nav-collapse -->
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>


    <div id="wrap">
       <div id="content">
           <div id="alerts">
               <div class="bs-docs-example">
              <div runat="server"  id="success_alert" class="success_alert alert alert-success fade in">
                <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="alert">&times;</button>
                   <div runat="server" id="success_alert_text">
                </div>
              </div>
             </div>
              <div class="bs-docs-example">
              <div runat="server" id="error_alert" class="error_alert alert alert-error fade in">
                <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="alert">&times;</button>
                <div runat="server" id="error_alert_text">
                </div>
              </div>
             </div>
            </div>
       <asp:ContentPlaceHolder ID="ContentPlaceHolder1" runat="server">

       </asp:ContentPlaceHolder>
       </div>


    </div>
    </form>
      <!-- Le javascript
    ================================================== -->
    <!-- Placed at the end of the document so the pages load faster -->

    <script type="text/javascript" src="assets/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Can you take your code and put it in this post?  hard to tell without seeing.

Comment: Okay I have added it, but really, it boils down to, a usercontrol in an aspx, the user control has a button that changes labels.

Comment: Try changing `conditionalmode` to always and set `ChildrenAsTriggers="true"`

Comment: Believe me, I have tried that.

Comment: I just tried it again, it still did not work.

Comment: @Milo check this [article](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb398780%28v=vs.100%29.aspx) and try that, i remember doing something similar for same issue long back. Expose `UpdatePanel` conditional mode as property and use another method to update `updatepanel`

Comment: I tried this article already and it did not work.

Comment: Did you try without any UpdateMode, ChildrenAsTriggers and Tiggers? I created sample project and used updatepanels without any conditions and it works for me. [My sample code](https://www.yousendit.com/download/UW13a0ZVNXYzS3A4SjhUQw)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe you are missing the code in your user control that publicly exposes the UpdateMode property and the Update method of the inner UpdatePanel control. You need this  so that an external source can explicitly refresh the contents of the user control. You need something like the following:

```
public UpdatePanelUpdateMode UpdateMode
{
    get { return this.UpdatePanel1.UpdateMode; }
    set { this.UpdatePanel1.UpdateMode = value; }
}

public void Update()
{
    this.UpdatePanel1.Update();
}
```

You can now can add the user controls to your .aspx page and set the UpdateMode property of the inner UpdatePanel control declaratively:

```
<div>
    <uc1:ProjectView ID="ProjectView1" runat="server" UpdateMode="Conditional" />
</div>
```

This process is explained well in the following document:

[Using the ASP.NET UpdatePanel Control with User Controls](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb398780%28v=vs.100%29.aspx)